# escaping quotes in java json

Tags: java, json

I'm preparing JSON and some part I do with

```
ls += "{ \"id\": \"" + list.indexOf(el) + "\", \"cell\" : [\"" +  el.toString() + "\"]}," ;
```

but when I check in Firebug what is sent I see that backslahes are not removed:

```
{"total":"1","page":"1","records":"1","rows":"[{ \"id\": \"0\", \"cell\" : [\"data1\"]},{ \"id\": \"1\", \"cell\" : [\"data2\"]}]"}
```

any ideas?
I tried with `ls.replaceAll("\\\\", " ");` but it doesn't work

Comment: That's strange, either way try `ls.replaceAll("\\","");` (otherwise it'll only replace two backslashes in a row..)

Comment: `ls.replaceAll("\\","");` gives regexsyntaxexception

Comment: Yeah that's right, my bad. Are you doing `ls = ls.replaceAll("\\\\,"")`, otherwise it won't save it to ls.

Comment: yes i'm saving it to another variable, it seems weird that backlashes are sent

Answer (score 0):

What JSON library are you using?  It looks to me like you're correctly building strings like

```
{ "id": "0", "cell" : ["data1"]}
```

but then inserting them *as strings* into some structure that is serialized by a JSON library.  The JSON serializer then has to re-escape the quotes to make the result into a valid JSON string literal.

Edit: you say you're using Gson, so I presume you have a top level class you're serializing which currently has a `String rows` property which you're filling with a JSON string. Instead you need to create a new class to represent one row

```
class Row {
  private String id;
  private List<String> cell;
  // constructor, getters and setters as usual
}
```

And change the rows property to be a `List<Row>`. Now rather than concatenating strings together to build the JSON yourself you simply populate your top-level object with the appropriate `Row` objects and let Gson handle converting them to JSON.

Comment: @donatello then you should build a class to represent the row data and let Gson handle turning it into JSON rather than trying to build the JSON string by hand.